# Iterate through dates

Tags: datetime

I want to create a one day per page calendar. I create the pages in a for loop, but I don't know how to save and increase it each iteration.

I thought about saving day, month and year separated, but then I would have to save how many days each month has and which years are leap years.

Is there a way to save a date and/or increase it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an old package, that temporarily sets the date with `\AdvanceDate`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{advdate}


\begin{document}
\ThisDay{0} % Set the day number to zero
\ThisMonth{1} % Start in January
%\ThisYear{2017} % for example
\foreach \x in {1,...,365} {%
  \AdvanceDate[\x]
  {\hfill\huge\textbf{\today}\hfill}  % Just as an example
  \clearpage
}

\end{document}
```

As can be seen from the screen shot the `\AdvanceDate` command is aware of leap years

[image]

Comment: @JohnKormylo I'd like to see such an example from TikZ calendar library because this is the sort of thing I've wanted to do myself using TikZ.  But, I've always found the TikZ calendar very frustrating to work with.  Could you post such an example?

Comment: @A.Ellett: Apparently there was another comment which was deleted? ;-)

Comment: Yes, there was a comment that TikZ calendar library could be easier to use... Hmm... I would have liked to see that answer too.

Comment: @A.Ellett: I've never used the TikZ calendar library so far. If there's such a solution, it should be added, of course

Comment: @A.Ellett I've got some examples that use `pgfcalendar` in [Displaying a Calendar](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/html/displaycalendar.shtml) if they're of any use.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot It would be nice to see two things: (1) a calendar for which the week starts on Sunday (since that's the convention where I'm from), and (2) the days can be configured on separate pages or create a calendar that fills the entire page

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer using pgf macros, see [Section 90 "Date and Calendar Utility Macros"](https://ftp.rrze.uni-erlangen.de/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#section.90) of the manual:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfcalendar}

\begin{document}
\pgfcalendar{cal}{2020-08-11}{2020-08-15}{%
  \centering\huge\bfseries%
  \pgfcalendarshorthand wt,                         % weekdayname,
  \pgfcalendarshorthand mt\ \pgfcalendarcurrentday, % monthname dayofmonth,
  \pgfcalendarcurrentyear\clearpage%                % year
}
\end{document}
```

The same, but using a shorthand as suggested by the manual:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfcalendar}

\begin{document}
\let\%=\pgfcalendarshorthand
\pgfcalendar{cal}{2020-08-11}{2020-08-15}{%
  \centering\huge\bfseries%
  \%wt, \%mt \%d0, \%y0\clearpage%
}
\end{document}
```

The first page looks like:

[image: Preview of the first page, having the text "Tuesday, August 11, 2020" on it.]